# Ignore the items in the ignore list by name in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I would like to ignore all the items in a ignore_list by name in python. For example consider

```
fruit_list = ["apple", "mango", "strawberry", "cherry", "peach","peach pie"]
allergy_list = ["cherry", "peach"]
good_list = [f for f in fruit_list if (f.lower() not in allergy_list)]
print good_list
```

I would like the good_list to ignore "peach pie" as well because peach is in the allergy list and peach pie contains peach :-P

Comment: Does "unimpeachable cannelloni" contain peach?

Comment: @DSM what kind of restaurants do you eat at? :)

Comment: @DeepakB: no need for `:-(`, you should be `:-)`!  It's much easier if you don't have to worry about breaking things into words and only have to detect substrings.

Comment: @Deepak If you don't have to split the list I'd suggest just using `f.find(allergy_item, 0, len(f))` to see if the `allergy_item` string appears in the `fruit_list` entry `f`. You seem to like list comprehension, but this can be adapted to be done using it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
fruits = ["apple", "mango", "strawberry", "cherry", "peach","peach pie"]
allergies = ["cherry", "peach"]

okay = [fruit for fruit in fruits if not any(allergy in fruit.split() for allergy in allergies)]
# ['apple', 'mango', 'strawberry']
```

Comment: `[f for f in fruits if not any(a in f.split() for a in allergies)]`

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to implement something like this. It depends on the formatting of the strings that you plan on using, but it works for this example. Just add it at the end of your example code. Feel free to ask for future clarification or how to deal with other formatting of entries in fruit_list.

```
good_list2=[]
for entry in good_list:
    newEntry=entry.split(' ')
    for split in newEntry:
        if not split in allergy_list:
             good_list2.append(split)

 print good_list2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> fruits = ["apple", "mango", "strawberry", "cherry", "peach","peach pie"]
>>> allergies = ["cherry", "peach"]
>>> [f for f in fruits if not filter(f.count,allergies)]
['apple', 'mango', 'strawberry']
>>>
```